# Write multifeature text classifier in sklearn

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn, text-classification

I am new to sklearn. I wrote a text classifier with the help of following link http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/rjweiss/7158866

In this link there is only one feature. Following example is working properly -

```
    add = open(file)
    add_data = []
    add_labels = []

    csv_reader = csv.reader(add)

    for line in csv_reader:
        add_labels.append(int(line[0]))
        add_data.append(line[1])

    add.close()

    trainset_size = int(round(len(add_data)*0.75))

    X_train = []
    y_train = []
    count = 0
    while count<trainset_size:
        X_train.append(add_data[count])
        y_train.append(add_labels[count])
        count = count + 1

    X_test = []
    y_test = []
    while count<len(add_data):
        X_test.append(add_data[count])
        y_test.append(add_labels[count])
        count = count + 1

    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2, ngram_range=(1, 1), stop_words='english', strip_accents='unicode', norm='l2')

    X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test)

    nb_classifier = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)
    #nb_classifier = LinearSVC().fit(X_train, y_train)
    #nb_classifier = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_nb_predicted = nb_classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Now I want to have two features per training data entry. So I wrote following code -

```
    add = open(file)
    add_data = []
    add_labels = []
    add_data_2 = []

    csv_reader = csv.reader(add)

    for line in csv_reader:
        add_labels.append(int(line[0]))
        add_data_2.append(str(line[1]))
        add_data.append(str(line[2]))

    add.close()

    trainset_size = int(round(len(add_data)*0.75))

    X_XX_train = []
    XX_train = []
    X_train = []
    y_train = []
    count = 0
    while count<trainset_size:
        X_train.append(add_data[count])
        XX_train.append(add_data_2[count])
        X_XX_train.append([add_data[count], add_data_2[count]])
        y_train.append(add_labels[count])
        count = count + 1


    X_XX_test = []
    X_test = []
    XX_test = []
    y_test = []
    while count<len(add_data):
        X_test.append(add_data[count])
        XX_test.append(add_data_2[count])
        X_XX_test.append([add_data[count], add_data_2[count]])
        y_test.append(add_labels[count])
        count = count + 1

    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2, ngram_range=(1, 1), stop_words='english', strip_accents='unicode', norm='l2')

    X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_XX_train)
    X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_XX_test)

    nb_classifier = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)
    #nb_classifier = LinearSVC().fit(X_train, y_train)
    #nb_classifier = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_nb_predicted = nb_classifier.predict(X_test)
```

It gives me following error -

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/XXX/PycharmProjects/add_classifier/src/my_classifier.py", line 162, in add_classifier_2
    X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_XX_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1282, in fit_transform
    X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 817, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 748, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 234, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 200, in <lambda>
    return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Is my method of including two features (here add_data and add_data_2) is wrong ??
I could not find proper example online !!

Comment: can you share examples of the input data? It is not clear what you means by one or two features.

Answer (score 0):

TfidfVectorizer expects a list of strings as input. `X_XX_train` is a list of list of strings. Depending on whether you want the same vocabulary for both parts of the text, you can either just concatenate the strings, or build a TfidfVectorizer for the two parts separately, and concatenate their output.